# Showing an image only within a certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple menu in an unordered list:

```
<ul class="courses">
   <a href="#">
     <li class="spinny">
        <h3>Course Title</h3>
        <img class="rotateme" src="images/logo_transparent.png"/>
     </li>
   </a>
</ul>
```

When the user hovers over the li item, the background changes colour and the img is displayed using a simple jQuery .toggle function:

```
$(".spinny").hover(function(){
            $(".rotateme").toggle("fast");
});
```

The image is also spinning thanks to some CSS3 animation, hence the class name rotateme, but I don't think that matters.

My problem is that the image is displayed on top of everything else, whereas I'd like to only show it within the bounds of the li item (as if it was a background-image essentially). How can I do this?

Also, how can I scale this up to multiple list items?

EDIT: Rough JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8yyT/). As you can see, the whole circle is shown. I just want to show it where it lies inside the grey box.

Comment: Can u provide jsfiddle with demo?

Comment: Why don't you prove that it isn't the CSS3 animations instead of *assuming* this? Simple to do: comment them out and give it a test!

Comment: @gvee prove _what_ isn't the CSS3 animations?

Comment: `.spinny { overflow: hidden; } `

Comment: @RobH Oh jeez, that was too simple. TGIF, thanks man. Put it in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall "The image is also spinning thanks to some CSS3 animation, hence the class name rotateme, but I don't think that matters." - prove that this doesn't matter.

Comment: @gvee why should the class name matter? I think you are trying to solve problems that don't exist.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - Fridays do odd things to us all.

Comment: @MrLister it's not the class name, it's the *assumption* that the CSS3 animations will not be causing or conflicting the problem. I *know* that this isn't the case in this scenario but why not take the guess work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.spinny { overflow: hidden; }
```

Is your easiest solution. Other than that, you'd have to set an appropriate size on the image so that it isn't bigger than the list item.

In response to your comment:

```
$(".spinny").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".rotateme").toggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Any idea how I can replicate this for multiple list items? I assume I need to include the image alongside each list item, but if they all have the same class name then the toggle will act on them all...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - added an edit for you (untested but should be okay)

Comment: Perfect. You are a god amongst mere mortals :)